# Selecting message queue approach for multiple consumers in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, queue, message-queue, amazon-sqs

Please help selecting a MQ app/system/approach for the following use-case:

Check for incoming messages for a specific user -> read the message if available -> delete from the queue, ideally, staying within AWS.

Context:

- Social networking app, users receiving messages, i.e.
  I need to identify incoming messages by recipient ID.
- The app is doing long-polls for new messages every 30 seconds.
- Message size is <1Kb.
- As per current estimates, I'll need 100M+ message checks per months in total (however, much less messages, these are just checks).
- While users acknowledge messages choosing OK or Ignore, however not sure if ACK support is required from MQ system for that.

I'm in AWS. Initially thought of SQS, but the more I read the less it looks like a good match - cannot set message recipient ID in a way to filter by recipient, etc, however maybe I'm wrong.
One of the options I also thought about is to just use DynamoDB's "messages" table, partition key being userId and sort key being a messageId, thus I'll be able to easily query by a user, however concerned with costs.

If possible, I would much more prefer to stay within AWS or at least use SAAS like SQS, as being a 1-person startup I really want to avoid headaches supporting self-hosted system.

Thank you!
D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right on both these counts:

- SQS won't work, because of the limitation you pointed.
- DynamoDB would work, but cost a lot.

I can suggest the following:

- Create a Redis cluster, possibly on [Amazon ElastiCache](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/).
- In it, make one [List](http://redis.io/topics/data-types) per user.
- Whenever a new message comes, append it to concerned User's list.
- To deliver the message, just read from the User's list. Also, flush the queue if needed.

What I am suggesting is very similar to how Twitter manages each User's news-feed and home-feed.

It should also be cheap.

Comment: Thank you, ketan!
Right, I see similar approaches used by Instagram and Tumblr and others as well.

Comment: Indeed. Done. Thanks again!